# My image is not visible in render

Tags: rendering

I'm just doing a simple 2D animation with a PNG file I made in GIMP. I have used this file before with no issue, so it is not a GIMP problem.
I can see my image perfectly until I get to render, than its all transparent. I have no idea why. One of the things I saw while googling this problem brought up checking my filters in the view layers properties and there is no filter option in my blender. I have uninstalled and installed again but no luck. I am very much a beginner so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess: you have imported your image as a "background image" or "reference image" objects? They are not renderable.

You need to create a mesh the same dimension of your image and assign the image as a texture in its material.

An easier way to do it is to use the addon [Import images as planes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/images_as_planes.html)

Search it in the Preferences' addon category, enable it. Then you will be able to go to File → Import → Image as plane → browse to your picture. That will create the mesh with material for you.